# I cannot access the navigation drawer menu fragments

Tags: java, android, firebase, navigation-drawer

I have added a navigation drawer menu in my Android project. When I press the items in the menu, I want it to direct it to that fragment, but it does not direct it, it does not give an error.There are 4 fragments, I want to reach them and do the necessary actions, such as writing comments, capturing the weather.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    HavaDurumu havadurumufragment;
    YorumlarFragment yorumlarFragment;
    YorumYazFragment yorumYazFragment;
    PuanVerFragment puanVerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        havadurumufragment=new HavaDurumu();
        yorumlarFragment=new YorumlarFragment();
        yorumYazFragment=new YorumYazFragment();
        puanVerFragment=new PuanVerFragment();
       // setFragment(havadurumufragment);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainframe,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id=item.getItemId();

        if(id==R.id.nav_hava){
            setFragment(havadurumufragment);
        }
        else if(id==R.id.nav_yorumyaz){
            setFragment(yorumYazFragment);
        }
        else if(id==R.id.nav_yorumlar){
            setFragment(yorumlarFragment);
        }
        else if (id==R.id.nav_puan){
            setFragment(puanVerFragment);
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geziproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Geziproject">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Geziproject.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".bos" />
        <activity android:name=".kayitol" />
        <activity android:name=".kullanicigiris" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the listener to the `NavigationView`

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: In `onCreate` you have a line of code  `NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);`, just add `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);` following to that line

Comment: I added the code above, as you said, it still did not improve.

Comment: @KübraOKUR wondering that you are making a manual fragment transaction, although that should be doing automatically by the `navController` >> what happens if you open the drawer and hit any fragment .. does it shows its layout on the screen?

Comment: I dont understand you

Comment: Ok no problem, can you show us the entire code.. possibly on github